# Pyodbc - The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: python, odbc, ms-access-2010, 32bit-64bit, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a MS Access Database (.accdb file) via python.

I used pyodbc to do this connection:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER = {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBG=C:\\test_db.accdb")
```

However, I got the following error:

```
('IM002, '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I went to the ODBC Data Source Administrator and when I tried to configure or remove the Driver I got the message:

```
Errors Found:
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

I found that this error is provoked by an incompatibility between versions of Windows (windows 7 - 64bit) and Microsoft Access (Office 2010 - 32bits).
I tried to reinstall the driver several times, both with 32 and 64bit versions but the problem wasn't solved.
Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using a 32-bit version of Python to run your code.

Comment: @GordThompson There isn't any alternative to use another version? I have several libraries and configurations that would be difficult to rebuild again, and my program needs them.

Comment: The other alternative would be to uninstall 32-bit Office and then install 64-bit Office so you would have the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine.

Comment: @GordThompson And could it read files created with the 32-bit MS Access version? The database to which I'm trying to connect my program is in a server and I cannot change it.

Comment: Yes. The database files themselves are the same whether they are created using the 32-bit or the 64-bit Access Database Engine.

Comment: @GordThompson Good, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: @GordThompson, typically you don't have 32-bit **and** 64-bit Office available (for free) at the same time. Using some hacks (see https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html) it is possible to install 32-bit and 64-bit MS Access Database Engine (which can be downloaded for free). Then any pyodbc should work.

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure the Python version matches the ODBC driver version: 32-bit with 32-bit, 64-bit with 64-bit.

It looks like you have 64-bit Python / pyodbc and 32-bit MS Access.

What you'll need to do is install the 32-bit Python version, and then install `pyodbc`.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. I checked and I have 64-bit python. There isn't any alternative, instead of reinstall it? I have several libraries and configurations that would be difficult to rebuild again.

Comment: I could use another library than pyodbc. The only thing that I want is to import/export data from my python program to this ms access database.